# Custom Google Map (with markers) + Custom .json embed to website

Tags: json, api, google-maps

Been trying to get my head around this for some time although clearly i'm missing something

what i am trying to do is not draw a new map although provide a src link to say (https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1xI_dALvs0A-oySG-dkf4BYeDyBk) to something of the below

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

I want to embed my custom map with the markers to my site and styling it

I guess map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') has something to do with the drawing of the new map although not too sure as to take it out or what.

1. is there anyway to use the custom map + .json code rather than hard coding an array of poi's as would like to rely on it pointing through to the custom map link for the markers
2. is there any better way to get around this

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps JavaScript API can load data that were stored in [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format. So you have to look into GeoJSON specification and create corresponding file for your markers (or polylines, polygons, etc.).

The Google Maps JavaScript API documentation explains how to load the GeoJSON data via Data layer of maps:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson

You should combine the styling example with GeoJSON example from the documentation to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the github link - https://github.com/hpi1hpi/custom-google-map-with-json

Add google map with custom color and data from JSON with slider